# CSV Files -How to Handle Bad Layers

Tags: qgis, csv

I have moved my QGIS Project to a new Directory. On opening the project in new folder, Handle Bad Layer window pops up with a list of shp and csv files. I am able to correct the shp files using browse button but browse button is disabled when I am trying to provide the new path for csv files.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Your post as it reads is a bit vague, please edit and include a question.

Answer (score 2):

You needn't go into the .qgz file. Although there is no browse button, you can edit the file path in the "Datasource" field of the "Handle Unavailable Layers" window that pops up when you first open the project in QGIS. Click "Apply Changes" after the edit and if the window or line disappears, then the new path is working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could open the project file in a text editor like Notepad++ and replace the old csv folder path(s) to the new and save it.  The project file is just xml so you can open, read, and write to the file.

Comment: when I am trying to open with Notepad, it's showing some strange characters

Comment: Open the .qgs file not the .qgs.qgz file

Comment: I only see qgz file, from where I can restore qgs file

Comment: Open the QGZ file with something like 7zip, or use another utility to unzip the QGZ file into its components.

Comment: I could retrieve the qgs files; however, editing the path in qgs file using Notepad is not handling the csv bad layer in qgz file. In qgz file, it's still showing old path.

Comment: I believe Notepad++ is not saving the edits